# What is with my code missing an IN or OUT parameter at index:: 12

Tags: java

I can't figure out what this error means in my Java code.

```
private static final String INPUT_FILE = "res/resprop.txt";
private static final String SELECT_MAX_ID = "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM RES";
private static final String INSERT_STMT = "INSERT INTO RES(ID, LEGALDESCRIPTION, ADDRESS, QUADRANT, ZONE, ASKINGPRICE, COMMENTS, AREA, BATHROOMS, BEDROOMS, GARAGE) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
private static final String UPDATE_STMT = "UPDATE RES SET ID = ?, LEGALDESCRIPTION = ?, ADDRESS = ?, QUADRANT = ?, ZONE = ?, ASKINGPRICE = ?, COMMENTS = ?, AREA = ?, BATHROOMS = ?, BEDROOMS = ?, GARAGE = ? where ID = ?";
private static final String SELECT_ID_STMT = "SELECT * FROM RES where ID = ?";
private static final String SELECT_LEGALDESCRIPTION_STMT = "SELECT * FROM RES where LEGALDESCRIPTION = ?";
private static final String SELECT_QUADRANT_STMT = "SELECT * FROM RES where QUADRANT = ?";
private static final String SELECT_PRICE_STMT = "SELECT * FROM RES where ASKINGPRICE = ?";
```

The error is thrown at this following line "int rowCount = pStat.executeUpdate();"

I am not sure as to why there is a problem, I have never heard of an in or out parameter. Additionally it is called java.sql.SQLException.

```
private boolean updatePreparedStatement(ResidentialProperty rp)
{
    try
    {

        PreparedStatement pStat = conn.prepareStatement(UPDATE_STMT);
        pStat.setLong(1, rp.getId());
        pStat.setString(2, rp.getLegalDescription());
        pStat.setString(3, rp.getAddress());
        pStat.setString(4, rp.getQuadrant());
        pStat.setString(5, rp.getZone());
        pStat.setDouble(6, rp.getAskingPrice());
        pStat.setString(7, rp.getComments());
        pStat.setDouble(8, rp.getArea());
        pStat.setDouble(9, rp.getBathrooms());
        pStat.setInt(10, rp.getBedrooms());
        pStat.setString(11, rp.getGarage()+"");

        int rowCount = pStat.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("row count = "+ rowCount);
        pStat.close();
        return rowCount == 1;

    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;

}

java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 12
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1752)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3444)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3530)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
at saitMLS.persistance.property.ResidentialPropertyBroker.updatePreparedStatement(ResidentialPropertyBroker.java:221)
at saitMLS.persistance.property.ResidentialPropertyBroker.persist(ResidentialPropertyBroker.java:263)
at saitMLS.problemDomain.property.UserInterface$1.actionPerformed(UserInterface.java:670)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Show us the _full and exact_ exception and stacktrace. Also, count the number of `?` in your query then count the number of items you used to fill in those `?` and you may see the problem...

Comment: Your `UPDATE_STMT` has **12** `?` placeholders. But you only set 11 before your call. `pStat.setLong(12, rp.getId());`

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the 12th parameter to `PreparedStatement` for the execution of the update query, so add it as shown below:

```
pStat.setLong(12, rp.getId());
```

However, I suggest, the better way is, you don't need to set the `ID` again (i.e., as 1st parameter) in your `UPDATE_STMT` statement, so change the code as shown below:

```
    pStat.setString(1, rp.getAddress());
    pStat.setString(2, rp.getQuadrant());
    //add others here
    pStat.setString(10, rp.getGarage()+"");
    pStat.setLong(11, rp. getId());
```

**QUERY:**

```
UPDATE_STMT = "UPDATE RES SET LEGALDESCRIPTION = ?, 
 ADDRESS = ?, QUADRANT = ?, ZONE = ?, ASKINGPRICE = ?, COMMENTS = ?, 
 AREA = ?, BATHROOMS = ?, BEDROOMS = ?, GARAGE = ? where ID = ?";
```

Comment: Did you get my point above? You are setting the id also again, which is unnecessary.

Comment: Also, you can upvote and accept my answer if it helps